# Why do results of matching depend on order of data (MatchIt package)?

Tags: r, matching

When using the matchit-function for full matching, the results differ by the order of the input dataframe. That is, if the order of the data is changed, results change, too. This is surprising, because in my understanding, the optimal full algorithm should yield only one single best solution.

Am I missing something or is this an error?

Similar differences occur with the optimal algorithm.

Below you find a reproducible example. Subclasses should be identical for the two data sets, which they are not. 
Thank you for your help!

```
# create data
nr <- c(1:100)
x1 <- rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=20)
x2 <- c(rep("a", 20),rep("b", 60), rep("c", 20))
x3 <- rnorm(100, mean=230, sd=2)
outcome <- rnorm(100, mean=500, sd=20)
group <- c(rep(0, 50),rep(1, 50))

df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, outcome=outcome, group=group, row.names=nr, nr=nr)
df_neworder <- df[order(outcome),]  # re-order data.frame

# perform matching
model_oldorder <- matchit(group~x1, data=df, method="full", distance ="logit")
model_neworder <- matchit(group~x1, data=df_neworder, method="full", distance ="logit")

# store matching results
matcheddata_oldorder <- match.data(model_oldorder, distance="pscore")
matcheddata_neworder <- match.data(model_neworder, distance="pscore")


# Results based on original data.frame
head(matcheddata_oldorder[order(nr),], 10)
          x1 x2  outcome group nr    pscore weights subclass
1  69.773776  a 489.1769     0  1 0.5409943     1.0       27
2  63.949637  a 529.2733     0  2 0.5283582     1.0       32
3  52.217666  a 526.7928     0  3 0.5028106     0.5       17
4  48.936397  a 492.9255     0  4 0.4956569     1.0        9
5  36.501507  a 512.9301     0  5 0.4685876     1.0       16


# Results based on re-ordered data.frame
head(matcheddata_neworder[order(matcheddata_neworder$nr),], 10)
          x1 x2  outcome group nr    pscore weights subclass
1  69.773776  a 489.1769     0  1 0.5409943     1.0       25
2  63.949637  a 529.2733     0  2 0.5283582     1.0       31
3  52.217666  a 526.7928     0  3 0.5028106     0.5       15
4  48.936397  a 492.9255     0  4 0.4956569     1.0        7
5  36.501507  a 512.9301     0  5 0.4685876     2.0       14
```

Apparently, the assignment of objects to subclasses differs. In my understanding, this should not be the case.

Comment: does the matching algorithm depend on any random numbers? if so you need to set your seed before running any code? I would also do that because you are generating data from `rnorm` and it will make the problem reproducible.

Comment: also try to keep your vectors and variable names different

Comment: The algorithm should not depend on random numbers, if I understand it correctly. However, I re-tried with setting a seed before running the code, but results again differ.

Answer (score 0):

The developers of the optmatch package (which the matchit function calls) provided useful help:

> I think what we're seeing here is the result of the tolerance argument
>   that fullmatch has. The matching algorithm requires integer distances,
>   so we have to scale then truncate floating point distances. For a
>   given set of integer distances, there may be multiple matchings that
>   achieve the minimum, so the solver is free to pick among these
>   non-unique solutions.

```
Developing your example a little more:
> library(optmatch) 
> nr <- c(1:100) x1 <- rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=20)
> outcome <- rnorm(100, mean=500, sd=20) group <- c(rep(0, 50),rep(1, 50)) 
> df_oldorder <- data.frame(x1=x1, outcome=outcome, group=group, row.names=nr, nr=nr) > df_neworder <- df_oldorder[order(outcome),]  # > re-order data.frame 
> glm_oldorder <- match_on(glm(group~x1, > data=df_oldorder), data = df_oldorder) 
> glm_neworder <- > match_on(glm(group~x1, data=df_neworder), data = df_neworder) 
> fm_old <- fullmatch(glm_oldorder, data=df_oldorder) 
> fm_new <- fullmatch(glm_neworder, data=df_neworder)

> mean(sapply(matched.distances(fm_old, glm_oldorder), mean))
> ## 0.06216174 

> mean(sapply(matched.distances(fm_new, glm_neworder), mean))
> ## 0.062058 mean(sapply(matched.distances(fm_old, glm_oldorder), mean)) -  

> mean(sapply(matched.distances(fm_new, glm_neworder), mean))
> ## 0.00010373
```

which we can see is smaller than the default tolerance of 0.001. You can always decrease the tolerance level, which may

> require increased run time, in order to get closer to the true
>   floating put minimum. We found 0.001 seemed to work well in practice,
>   but there is nothing special about this value.